# Optimizing selection in a matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Is there an algorithm that would maximize the `sum` given a matrix like the one below, where each row/column can only be used once? (outside of the obvious brute-force method)

Also, does anybody know what this type of problem is called?

[image]

Comment: Do you know of any imperfect algorithms that would create a "good but not perfect"-type solution?

Comment: @eminem That's called the Greedy Algorithm, and is not typically optimal for this kind of problem: it maximizes the objective iff the problem is a weighted matroid, or the matrix of match values is supermodular. You can solve this problem using a relatively simple algorithm called the Kuhn-Munkres algorithm, with running time $O(n^3)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a combinatorial optimization problem which looks for optimal assignments. Have a look at the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), this could be the answer to your question.

**Edit**:
It might be interesting for you that there is also an implementation of this algorithm in python ([`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)).

Comment: That seems to be it, thanks!